# Help finding a jQuery Marquee that will work with images?

Tags: jquery, marquee

I have seen all these jQuery marquee plugins all over the place but all they do is scroll words.

Can I use HTML and CSS to make them show say a Profile picture, the persons name, and thir last post?

Can that be done or do I need a different plugin for that?

Answer (score 1):

I recently used this one: http://www.vegabit.com/jquery_scroller/

You can put anything you want in the scroller

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // initialize scrollable
        $('.horizontal_scroller').SetScroller({ velocity: 85,
            direction: 'horizontal',
            startfrom: 'right',
            loop: 'infinite',
            movetype: 'linear',
            onmouseover: 'pause',
            onmouseout: 'play',
            onstartup: 'play',
            cursor: 'pointer'
        });
    });

</script>
<div class="horizontal_scroller" id="no_mouse_events">
     <div class="users">
           <div class="user">
                <div><img src="" /></div>
                <div>Name: </div>
                <div class="lastpost"></div>
           </div>
           <div class="user">
                <div><img src="" /></div>
                <div>Name: </div>
                <div class="lastpost"></div>
           </div>
           <div class="user"><
                <div><img src="" /></div>
                <div>Name: </div>
                <div class="lastpost"></div>
           </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the link. checking it out now it looks like it may be able to work if i can throw in an array so i can have multiple users list in it!

Comment: I am waiting to hear back from the guy that wrote it not sure if this will show my stuff back to back with out a gap. if you have any other sugestions i'll look at them while i am waiting!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your correctly.  But I'm thinking you can do: <div class="users"><div class="user">...</div><div class="user">...</div>...</div>

Comment: I just added some sample code.  Not sure what language you are using, but you'll need to populate the users list with a loop or something.  Then you should be able to add css to make it look like how you want

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are animating an inner element within an element with `overflow: hidden`, you should be able to put what you want in there, including an image.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do with some minor changes to this:

http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Comment: i found that one as well i need to figure out how to get it to go all the time not leave a big white space if you know what i mean?